# How to access session of one site from other site

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I have website w1 written in rails using auhtlogic for authentication and w2 in PHP(say), I want w2 to access session information stored by w2 and login user into w2 and also retrieve user_id from session.

Comment: I think you mean you want w2 to access session information stored by w1 .

Comment: @shreyas yes! I want w2 to access session information stored by w1

Answer (score 2):

By default, Rack (which Rails uses to manage its sessions) stores session information in cookies by marshalling the session hash (see [here](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb#L72)), which results in a string that is specific to Ruby. It would be extremely difficult to use PHP to deserialize this information.

If you're dead set on doing this, you're going to have to handle the session serialization yourself. I think a full solution is outside the scope of a single question on SO, but a few pointers:

- It would be wise to store only a session id in the cookie, and then keep the actual session data in a database that would be accessible from both the PHP and Rails apps. If you really want to keep the session information in a cookie (or in another place like memcached, where you'd also have to serialize it), look into serialization strategies that work across languages, like [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/).
- You'll want to do something to ensure that the cookie is not tampered with by the user. Rack uses [HMAC](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb#L92), which is a good solution. I've never used PHP, but I'm sure they also have a library for it.
- You probably already know this, but just in case: This is all assuming that your two apps are sharing the same domain name. If they're not, then your users' browsers won't share the cookie between the two apps, and there's not really anything you can do. For example, you could share sessions between railsapp.yourdomain.com and phpapp.yourdomain.com, but not railsapp.com and phpapp.com.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i tried a solution sometime ago that was more a hack, but for my propose it worked.

after login, i used to write the user's cookie in a file in a public directory and when this user tried to access the other server where he had to access too, my application on this second server, just had to "know how to access" the remote file stored in the first server and load this content as cookie. I did used CURL at that time.

**Note** that it introduce some security breaches, and probably your security will rely on "obscurity" - for example, the algorithm to mount the file name where the cookie is stored and how to access it and any external webserver configuration.. Said that, i think we could think as well use a shared memcached to store the cookies..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Open ID?